# Docking: RCS translation with joystick

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I'm having a problem with my joystick setup for RCS translation.

What I expected to happen: In linear docking mode, I'd expect the joystick inputs to trigger translation only.

What actually happens: In linear docking mode, joystick inputs simultaneously trigger translation *and* rotation. I.e. if I tilt the stick to the right, the RCS thrusters try to translate right and yaw right at the same time. This makes docking with the joystick impossible.

I have my Thrustmaster joystick mapped like this:

- Joystick left/right: Yaw, translate left/right.
- Joystick forward/back: Pitch, translate forward/back.
- Joystick twist: Roll, translate up/down.
- One of the joystick buttons: Toggle linear/rotation docking mode.

Have I run into a bug, or is this the expected behavior? Can I make the input mapping work as I had expected it to? Or, would you suggest an alternate joystick configuration that work reasonably well for docking? I'm not picky about the specific setup; I just want to be able to use the joystick for translation.

Edit: I mean that I want *analog* joystick controls for translation. Anything that's just on/off is pretty much the same as the keyboard.

Comment: _if I tilt the stick to the right, the RCS thrusters try to translate right and yaw right at the same time_ But you have this mapped: _Joystick left/right: Yaw, translate left/right._  Sounds like that is your problem. (or am I missing something here?)

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to toggle the modes for each analog axis. For example, under "Pitch Axis" click the button that's initially labeled "None." Click "Clear." Turn off the green lights for staging and rotation. Leave the green light for translation on. Move the joystick forward and press "Accept."

**Important:** Due to an apparent bug, you must turn off the green lights *before* you move the joystick. If you move the joystick first, your changes to the green lights will be forgotten after you click "Accept."

Answer (score 1):

it's in how you have your joystick mapped.

i personally mapped the linear translations to a pair of buttons on the throttle(forward/reverse) and the hat on the joystick(up/down/left/right) and it works fine.

i'm also using a thrustmaster.

the only constraints on that setup are having the necessary buttons and the hat. once you get used to it you can fly circles around a station pretty easily.

Comment: So just to be clear: You're suggesting not using analog controls for translation?

Comment: you're still using analog controls, just more sensible ones. having immediate access to rotation as well as translation is incredibly useful. 

you might also want to check your control mapping and make sure that under the linear translation section you don't have the joystick tagged for rotational, too. you want to have those sections very clearly defined or it'll give you fits.

Comment: Oh, does your Thrustmaster have an analog hat? The hat on mine is not analog, sadly. Maybe that's the reason I was confused about your answer.

Comment: it's not particularly delicate or discriminatory(narrow range of motion) but it works as analog. it's a little insensitive(in linux at least) though. even a non-analog hat would work pretty well, though. you want to do your lineup well back anyways.